# Docker build takes too long

Tags: docker

Certain instructions in my Dockerfiles are taking too long. For example, adding a 3 lines file with the `ADD` instruction or echoing a line into a file sometimes takes more than a minute.

## What can be causing this?

Here's my syslog, not sure if relevant:

```
May 29 18:45:17 mymachine kernel: [97813.649053] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:45:54 mymachine kernel: [97850.627286] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:45:55 mymachine kernel: [97851.249484] EXT4-fs (dm-4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:46:34 mymachine console-kit-daemon[983]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 5102 was not found when attempting to remove it
May 29 18:46:53 mymachine kernel: [97908.977215] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:46:53 mymachine kernel: [97909.217137] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:46:53 mymachine kernel: [97909.247252] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:47:26 mymachine kernel: [97942.607378] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:47:26 mymachine kernel: [97942.767831] EXT4-fs (dm-4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:48:36 mymachine kernel: [98012.632630] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:48:37 mymachine kernel: [98013.681835] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:48:38 mymachine kernel: [98014.009612] netlink: 1 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
May 29 18:48:38 mymachine kernel: [98014.016816] device vethb49f entered promiscuous mode
May 29 18:48:38 mymachine kernel: [98014.020408] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethb49f: link is not ready
May 29 18:48:38 mymachine kernel: [98014.046745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethb49f: link becomes ready
May 29 18:48:38 mymachine kernel: [98014.046785] docker0: port 2(vethb49f) entered forwarding state
May 29 18:48:38 mymachine kernel: [98014.046791] docker0: port 2(vethb49f) entered forwarding state
May 29 18:48:39 mymachine kernel: [98015.128850] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:48:39 mymachine kernel: [98015.174370] docker0: port 2(vethb49f) entered disabled state
May 29 18:48:39 mymachine kernel: [98015.174860] device vethb49f left promiscuous mode
May 29 18:48:39 mymachine kernel: [98015.174867] docker0: port 2(vethb49f) entered disabled state
May 29 18:49:18 mymachine kernel: [98054.703978] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:49:18 mymachine kernel: [98054.834326] EXT4-fs (dm-4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:50:14 mymachine kernel: [98110.408736] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:50:15 mymachine kernel: [98111.221056] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:50:15 mymachine kernel: [98111.443577] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:50:44 mymachine kernel: [98140.675447] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:50:44 mymachine kernel: [98140.695348] EXT4-fs (dm-4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.027431] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.559271] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.800718] netlink: 1 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.881484] device veth000f entered promiscuous mode
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.881966] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth000f: link is not ready
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.945999] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth000f: link becomes ready
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.946045] docker0: port 2(veth000f) entered forwarding state
May 29 18:51:36 mymachine kernel: [98192.946051] docker0: port 2(veth000f) entered forwarding state
May 29 18:51:37 mymachine kernel: [98193.274007] docker0: port 2(veth000f) entered disabled state
May 29 18:51:37 mymachine kernel: [98193.275061] device veth000f left promiscuous mode
May 29 18:51:37 mymachine kernel: [98193.275068] docker0: port 2(veth000f) entered disabled state
May 29 18:51:37 mymachine kernel: [98193.319695] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:52:17 mymachine kernel: [98233.520926] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
May 29 18:52:17 mymachine kernel: [98233.608787] EXT4-fs (dm-4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
```

Docker info:

```
Containers: 2
Images: 172
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-1447309-pool
 Data file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 4443.4 Mb
 Data Space Total: 102400.0 Mb
 Metadata Space Used: 9.4 Mb
 Metadata Space Total: 2048.0 Mb
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-24-generic
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and provides no information on which to base an answer.  Please (re)read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: @JimGarrison Do you even use Docker? I have been here for years and this question seems fine to me. Docker is new software and there are quit a lot of problems with it, debugging it is hard. Please (re)read the question.

Comment: Added some style to the question, for the people who didn't bother reading it and just voted for closing it because they don't have better things to do.

Comment: You have not provided the actual file that is causing the problem, and no way for anybody to attempt to duplicate the problem.  A log is meaningless unless we have a way to tie it to specific operations you are executing.

Comment: @JimGarrison There's nothing special about my Dockerfile, like I said I'm just using the `ADD` instruction to add a very simple file. The problem is Docker and its weird interactions with the kernel. You might not have run into this issue (again, do you even use Docker?), but others might. I have helped many people with problems like mine, having less information. Sometimes the answer is as simple as "Ah yes, this happens when docker does X. You just have to Y". This is why you shouldn't treat stackoverflow as your job nor try to answer questions about subjects you have no clue about.

Comment: I guess my mistake was adding the tag "linux". Sometimes the quality of the answers depends entirely on the chosen tags.

Comment: ...by the way -- instead of getting angry at folks who vote to close, you might consider improving the question. There really _isn't_ enough information here to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't know what extra info I could add. Instead of trolling me, downvoting and voting for closing it, previous commenter (not you) could have asked me the same things you did... If only he knew anything about Docker, but of course he doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Docker backend are you running? AUFS? device-mapper? btrfs? ...?

Switching to the AUFS backend, if your operating system supports it, is likely to be helpful here.

A more authoritative answer would require knowing which backend you're using, the performance characteristics of the system you're on, and perhaps a trace of its invocation (such as what sysdig can generate).

Comment: I added my docker info, just remembered that command existed. I'm using device-mapper, but it's not like I chose it, it came like that by default. I can try with AUFS, but I thought using the defaults was better. I mean I wouldn't like building everything with it and then find out Docker deprecated its usage. I don't seem to have the sysdig command, I'll research it. Thanks.

Comment: device-mapper was added mostly because it's portable -- works with basically all distros' kernels -- not because it's fast, which it isn't; needing to mount and unmount filesystems all the time, and potentially fsck them if something wasn't unmounted / read-only when it was branched off into a snapshot, can certainly slow things down. A trace, as with sysdig, will allow a determination of whether this is really your problem.

Comment: Oh wow that should be like the first thing they tell us when installing. And now I'm noticing the docker in my dev machine is using AUFS (here everything works fine). Thanks, you have been very helpful. I'll come back if I solve this.

Comment: Switching to AUFS did solve the issue, builds run fast now. Btw in Ubuntu 14.04 that can be done simply by installing `linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` before installing Docker, and Docker will detect it automatically. Cheers.