# What is the difference between AUFS and devicemapper in docker?

Tags: virtualization, docker

When docker was introduced a big hype was made about docker using AUFS, allowing two different docker containers to use the same underlying layers, and thus reducing some of the overhead. Docker now seems to prefer devicemapper (e.g. default in Ubuntu 14.04). Does devicemapper provide the same functionality, or did people figure out that the advantages are not too big using AUFS ?

Comment: BTW, this might be a better question for Server Fault than Stack Overflow, since it's a question about configuration of system-level tooling, rather than about programming as such.

Comment: BTW, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23943691/14122 might be of interest to you -- read the full comment history.

Comment: Not sure how I can migrate (or flag for migration) my question to Server Fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/filesystems/) details the differences between the storage backends available to docker. Devicemapper support was implemented since AUFS is not included in the kernel and thus was only available on systems (such as Ubuntu) that provided it. Because of this  it is generally not recommended in production environments.

Comment: If my production environment is based on ubuntu, is there any reason not to use AUFS?

Comment: Even Ubuntu [will deprecate AUFS](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-March/034880.html) in a future release. Since AUFS will never be accepted in the mainline Linux kernel I would not choose it for new projects.

Answer (score 1):

No, devicemapper does not provide the same functionality -- it's much, **much** slower; since it operates at the block-device layer, it needs to deal with mounting, unmounting, fsck'ing, etc.

The reason it's widely used is that many distributions' kernels do not support AUFS. However, if you *can* use AUFS, you probably *should*.

Comment: so, both devicemapper and AUFS can create and merge layers, but they do it in a completely different way?

Comment: Correct, and with a completely different on-disk representation.